# Yet another "Object is possibly 'undefined'", but it really can't be

Tags: typescript, undefined

TS is reporting a classic "Object is possibly 'undefined'" error with the below code, yet it is impossible for the value to be undefined. What is causing this error to be reported? A link to the docs where this behavior is described would be great!

```
const maybeTrue = Math.random() < 0.5;

let myStr;

if (maybeTrue) {
  myStr = 'abc';
}

if (maybeTrue) {
  console.log(myStr.toLowerCase()); // Error here, `myStr` possibly undefined
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwJ4CMCmAVATgVzTAXhgFkEoALAOiwTABMQ4AKAShgB4YAGSgVgFgAUEIA2aWHCQBlKFiEBLAGYwmiVJlxo2AbyEx402YRgByBCmAmhAXyELlq5Omx4demKEggxlESADmqoZYlFAgADIgAO5oWADCCBBorCw2QA)

Comment: See [microsoft/TypeScript#12184](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184); being able to "save" results of control flow analysis would be useful in cases like this, but probably not feasible to implement in a performant way.

Comment: I take this as a rule of thumb,
"The compiler can only narrow the variable(s) directly involved in the guard expression", from [post](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32639#issuecomment-516952575)

Comment: I don't follow the question since `myStr` certainly will be `undefined` if that `if` is not entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler does a static analysis of the code. This analysis reveals that the statement that reads the value of `myStr` can be reached through a code path that initializes `myStr` (when the condition of the first `if` is `true`) or a code path that skips the initialization.

The compiler does not run the code, it does not evaluate the conditions, it does not "notice" that both `if` statements use the same condition.

For the analysis both `if`s look like `if (<condition>) { <statements> }`. All it matters for it is that `<statements>` are not executed on all code paths, therefore after the first `if` statement `myStr` might be or might not be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

As is see in the playground script. The reported error is clear in the way that `let` declare the variable but it is not initialized, so it is `undefined`.

Then the string type is inferred from your assignment inside the conditional sentence.

I don't believe typescript compiler can infer that in the second conditional the variable is initialized and is a string. I have seen some GitHub issues related to this, I can not find any to link unfortunately.

But we can test it somehow, in the playground you provided:

- If we initialize the variable to empty string, the error disappear.

```
const maybeTrue = Math.random() < 0.5

let myStr = ""
if (maybeTrue) {
  myStr = 'abc'
}

if (maybeTrue) {
  console.log(myStr.toLowerCase())
}
```

- If we move the `console.log` sentence to first `if`, the error is not reported.

```
const maybeTrue = Math.random() < 0.5

let myStr = ""
if (maybeTrue) {
  myStr = 'abc'
  console.log(myStr.toLowerCase())
}
```

Take a look here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html and here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html for more detailed information about how types are implemented